# CSS scale out and fade effect

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to recreate the following effect (click one of the colours on this page to see what I mean: http://flatuicolors.com) on an overlay when a link is clicked.

The transition is something like this: An overlay with a success message scales out and fades in, pauses and then scales out and fades out.

However, it is not producing the desired effect. What's more, the scaling is not visible at all. Any help is much appreciated.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
.container { 
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto; }
.container.questionnaire { 
    background:#f1c40f; 
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.row-flex.buttons-only { 
    height:100%;}
.row-flex {
    display: table;
    width: 100%; } 
.column { 
    box-sizing: border-box; }
.one-third-flex.column {
    width: 33.3333%; 
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none; }
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
     display: table;
    background-color:#1abc9c;
    z-index: 10;
}
h1.success-message { display: table-cell; text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;}

.animated { 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut { 
    0% {visibility:visible; opacity: 1;transform: scale(2);} 
    40% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(1.5);} 
    60% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(1.5);} 
    100% {visibility:hidden; opacity: 0;transform: scale(1);} 
} 
@keyframes fadeOut { 
    0% {visibility:visible; opacity: 1; transform: scale(2);} 
    40% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(1.5);} 
    60% {opacity: 1;transform: scale(1.5);} 
    100% {visibility:hidden;opacity: 0; transform: scale(1);} 
} 
.fadeOut { 
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut; 
    animation-name: fadeOut; 
}
```

```html
<body>
    
  <div class="overlay animated fadeOut"><h1 class="success-message">Success</h1></div>
  <div class="container questionnaire">
    <div class="row row-flex buttons-only">
        <div class="one-third-flex column"></div>
        <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">
            <div role="button" class="ico-btn btn-settings-lg"><a href="#">CLICK</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third-flex column"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There must be a bit of JS in here. You can't link your actions (clicks) and animations only using CSS.

Comment: Thans for the reply Sebastien. I'm aware there is no JS, I'm only looking for a solution with regards to the frame animation. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I hope this answer may help you.

As I thought that was an interesting effect (created with flash), I have worked a bit creating it from scratch with css3 and jquery. It was easier for me to do my code insteed of trying to modify yours so that’s why It maybe not be usefull for You but maybe it may be for other users.

The html is simple:

```
<div class="square ">
 </div>
 <div class="effect ">
<div class="text">TEXT HERE</div>
 </div>
```

Where `square` is the area to click and `effect` is the container of the animation, which is a div with 0 height and width  placed at the center of the window in case you want to add more animations (as to make it “grow” or shrink).

With, also, some simple jquery:

```
$('. square).click(function () {
    $('. effect).addClass("animation");
    $('.text').addClass("text-effect");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('. effect).removeClass("animation");
        $('.text').removeClass("text-effect");
    }, 1500); 
});
```

to add a class to `effect` and `text` on click and remove it after animation is done

Then after some basic CSS styles I made the animation for `effect`:

```
.animation {
     animation-name: background;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    }
@keyframes background {
    0%   {height:100%; width:100%; opacity:1}
    80% {height:100%; width:100%; opacity:1}
    99.999% {height:100%; width:100%; opacity:0}
    100% {height:0; width:0; opacity:0}
}
```

And for the `text` I have just used a transition:

```
.text {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weignt:bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000000;
    font-family:arial;
    padding:20px 0;
    transition:all 0.2s linear;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition:all 0.2s linear;
}

.text-effect {
    padding:10px 0;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

All toguether and adding 8 squares with different colors:

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/3ngzq40y/5/)**

and, as I wrote above, the background fading and shrinking just with

```
@keyframes background {
    0%   {height:100%; width:100%; opacity:1}
    80% {height:100%; width:100%; opacity:1}
    100% {height:0; width:0; opacity:0}
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/3ngzq40y/7/)**